# How can I change my data from str to int?

Tags: python, string, binary, int

I have a Dataframe and in some columns I have "0" or "1".
I would print my data in a plot but jupyter can't understand my "0" and my "1" like numbers but for jupyter my data are str!
If I have a code like the following, how should I do to change from str to int so that I can printed them in a plot?

(I think that the following one should be the code to create a Dataframe, but it's not important. It's just to have an idea)

```
A= pd.DataFrame {'B':[1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1], 'C': [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0], 'D': [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1]}
```

Comment: Have you tried `...astype(int)`?

Answer (score 1):

just convert them to ints using this:

```
for col in A.columns: A[col] = A[col].astype(int)
```

or if it's just a subset of columns use:

```
for col = ['A','B','C'] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process column values through `lambda`. Something like:

```
A["some_column"] = A["some_column"].apply(lambda x: int(x))
```